# Cambiar texto de un TextView dentro de un CustomArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un `ListView` con un `CustomArrayAdapter` con `checkbox` , dentro del `Onclick` del `checkbox` en el `CustomArrayAdapter` quiero modificar el texto de un `TextView` del `Fragment` , he intentado esto pero no lo consigo, no me modifica el texto en el `Fragment` :

```
 public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Row> implements View.OnClickListener{

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    TextView crec;
private Context mcontext;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, List < Row > objects)
    {
        super(context, 0, objects);
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mcontext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // holder pattern
        Holder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new Holder();


            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listadapter_multiple, null);
            View convertView2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recomendacion, null);

            holder.setTextViewTitle((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle));
            holder.setTextViewSubtitle((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSubtitle));
            holder.setCheckBox((CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox));
            holder.helloTxt= (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.crec);


            convertView.setTag(holder);


        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final Row row = getItem(position);
        holder.getTextViewTitle().setText(row.getTitle());
        holder.getTextViewSubtitle().setText(row.getSubtitle());
        holder.getCheckBox().setTag(position);
        holder.getCheckBox().setChecked(row.isChecked());
        holder.getCheckBox().setOnClickListener(this);




        return convertView;
    }


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Holder holder = new Holder();

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;
    int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
    final Row row = getItem(position);

    if(checkBox.isChecked()) {
       holder.helloTxt.setText("eltexto");
        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

}
```

Mi Holder :

```
  static class Holder{

    TextView textViewTitle;
    TextView textViewSubtitle;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    public TextView helloTxt;

    public TextView getTextViewTitle()
    {
        return textViewTitle;
    }

    public void setTextViewTitle(TextView textViewTitle)
    {
        this.textViewTitle = textViewTitle;
    }
    public TextView getTextViewSubtitle()
    {
        return textViewSubtitle;
    }

    public void setTextViewSubtitle(TextView textViewSubtitle)
    {
        this.textViewSubtitle = textViewSubtitle;
    }
    public CheckBox getCheckBox()
    {
        return checkBox;
    }
    public void setCheckBox(CheckBox checkBox)
    {
        this.checkBox = checkBox;
    }

}
```

El TextView esta declarado en el Fragment , es un TextView normal:

```
public class Recomendacion extends Fragment {
   ...
   TextView crec;
   //codigo
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       ...
       crec = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.crec);
       //codigo
```

Comment: Fen Dev, por faor agrega tu clase Holder y especifica con una imagen o a más detalle que TextView deseas cambiar el texto

Comment: Ya está agregado al final del todo

Comment: Disculpa Fen Dev estaba con mucho trabajo, he agregado una respuesta!, dime que resultados tienes, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucione llamando una función en la `Activity` contenedor del `Fragment` :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Holder holder = new Holder();

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;
    int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
    final Row row = getItem(position);

    if(checkBox.isChecked()) {

        String retur = ((Principal) getContext()).Contador(true);

    }

}
```

En la `Activity` creo la función que modifica el `TextView` :

```
 public String Contador(boolean foo){
    TextView t = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    Fragment someFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.output);
    View fragmentView = someFragment.getView();
    String result = "Texto";

    if (foo) {

            t.setText(result);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Una propuesta sería agregar un método publico en el cual cambies el texto del `TextView` que deseas, esto dentro de la clase `Recomendacion` :

```
public void cambiaTexto(String Texto){
  //Cambia texto en TextView.
  crec.setText(Texto);
}
```

Dentro del método `onClick()` de tu Adapter `CustomArrayAdapter` envia el texto:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   CustomArrayAdapter.cambiaTexto("eltexto");
   ...
   ...
}
```

Con esto podrás cambiar el texto e tu `TextView` dentro de tu `Fragment` `Recomendacion`.

Comment: Lo probé me seteaba la variable pero no me refleja el cambio en el TextView , me pasa lo mismo que con la solución anterior que tenia.